# PHP copy an image, corrupt image

Tags: php

I have this command:

```
copy($value['formats']['format'], 'bookData/cover/'.$picturename);
```

When I open the image from `$value['formats']['format']` it is no problem. When I open the image from `bookData/cover`, the file must be corrupt. I can't open it with Windows image viewer and I can't open it with Adobe Photoshop.

I have already tried this:

```
$content = file_get_contents($value['formats']['format'));
$fp = fopen('bookData/cover/'.$picturename, "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

The same result. The server is an Apache with PHP7 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Does `$picturename` have the correct extension? Those programs may be using the extension to determine what kind of image it is.

Comment: Check the file size of the new file. Is it zero size? That might mean some error happened. Also try using the `cmp` command to check if both files are the same.

Comment: You should open the file in binary mode (`"wb"`).

Comment: Compare the contents of the files when downloaded, or provide some error message.